# Swift format input as percentage in "as-you-type" fashion

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield, percentage

I have a text field that calls a method to format the input as a percentage in an as-you-type fashion.

```
cell.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChangedIntoPercent(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

The method called:

```
@objc func textChangedIntoPercent (sender : UITextField) {
    
    if let amountString = sender.text?.percentInputFormatting() {
        sender.text = amountString
    }
}
```

The following code works well when entering numbers with the trailing % sign. However, when using backspace, nothing is deleted, the string just returns itself, and the last number is not backspaced. If I change the position of the cursor to just before the percent sign, I am able to delete the numbers.

```
func percentInputFormatting() -> String {
 
    var number: NSNumber!
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    
    var amountWithPrefix = self
    
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^0-9]", options: .caseInsensitive)
    amountWithPrefix = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: amountWithPrefix, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count), withTemplate: "")
    
    let double = (amountWithPrefix as NSString).doubleValue
    number = NSNumber(value: (double / 100))

    guard number != 0 as NSNumber else {
        return "0%"
    }
    
    return "\(formatter.string(from: number)!)" + "%"
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? Allow the user to delete the percent sign with backspace? Doesn't that contradict with your intention of automatically adding the percent sign...?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. No, I do not want the % sign to ever be able to be deleted, but I want the user to be able to backspace the number BEFORE the percent sign. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`shouldChangeCharactersIn`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield) delegate method to detect backspaces. In fact, I recommend that you implement the entire thing in this delegate method, rather than the action for `editingChanged`.

First, set the delegate if you haven't already:

```
cell.textField.delegate = self

...
```

Now implement `shouldChangeCharactersIn`. This method will be called when user edits the text field in some way, but *before* the text field's text actually changes. You can get what change the the user is trying to do from the parameters `range` and `string`. The user is trying to replace the range "`range`" in `textField.text` with the string in `string`.

If `string` is empty, that means the user is trying to delete stuff. We drop the last digit, and format the number again. Otherwise, apply the user's edits using `replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)`, and check if it is a valid number. If it is, format it.

We are supposed to return a `Bool` indicating whether the edit should be applied or not. In this case, since how the text field's text should change is 100% handled by us, we don't want to apply the user's edits.

```
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let oldText = textField.text else { return false }

        if string.isEmpty { // this means that backspace is pressed
            let oldDigits = textField.text?.digits
            // drops one digit every time backspace is pressed
            let newNumber = Double(oldDigits.dropLast()) ?? 0
            textField.text = percentFormatter.string(for: newNumber / 10000)
        } else // something has been entered
            if let newNumber = Double(
                    (oldText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string).digits
                  ) {
            textField.text = percentFormatter.string(for: newNumber / 10000)
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

where `percentFormatter` and `withoutNonDigits` are:

```
let percentFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let f = NumberFormatter()
    f.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    f.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    f.numberStyle = .percent
    f.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US_POSIX")
    return f
}()

extension String {
    var digits: String {
        filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus You know what, I'm quite fed up with implementing a complicated backspace feature that deletes multiple characters. I've found too many edge cases to handle. I feel that goes a bit outside the scope of this question anyway. I'm just going to delete the single last digit, otherwise make it a 0. :)

Comment: Never said it was in scope of the question. My comment was just FYI